# Error throws when using HOC in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This code throws "Cannot find name 'ComposedComponent'". And I don't understand why that's happend. Just want to create simple HOC.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StatelessComponent, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

interface Props {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
}

const AuthComponent = (ComposedComponent: React.ComponentType<Props>) => {

    class Authentication extends Component<Props> {

        componentWillMount() {
            if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
                this.context.router.push('/');
            }
        }

        componentWillUpdate(nextProps: Props) {
            if (!nextProps.isAuthenticated) {
                this.context.router.push('/');
            }
        }

        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props } />;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? I've just copied this to a project using 2.7.1 and it seems to work

Comment: Ohh, problem with extension of file. Should be *.tsx not *.ts. Any way thanks :).

Comment: Omg, I just had the exact same issue for hours. Was driving me crazy. Thank you! You should probably post it as an answer @TomaszKlęk :)

Answer (score 1):

Extension of the file should be `.tsx` instead of `.ts`